# Random unauthorized error

Tags: couchdb

We have a process submitting documents to couchdb. It works fine most of the time, but once in a while a design document will fail with

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a db or server admin."}
```

I am a bit stuck because I don't know why 100 or so documents would succeed but then one would fail. The same document has successfully been uploaded before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of CouchDB are you running?

Comment: Ok good.  Do you have any validation function?

Comment: I've just realised it occurs when a design doc is submitted (still only once in a while though).

Comment: btw the couchdb user I am using is db admin

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything that could cause this.  How are you authenticating?  Basic auth, cookies, oauth?

Comment: I am using cookies. Good point, maybe its an expiry thing?

Comment: Though, then other calls would fail afterwards I would assume. Maybe its a problem with the client I am using (LoveSeat)?.

Comment: One more thing. I see a lot of these in the log. GET /_config/query_servers/ 401  . Related?

Comment: Sorry - none of it makes sense.  I've not seen anything like this in hundreds of document updates (using http directly).  Maybe it is something in this client - although even that's hard to imagine.

Comment: It turns out it was cookie related. The cookies store in the client was being lost, because I was hosting it in an asp.net application. LoveSeat creates a new cookie store for every instance of CouchDatabase so either I needed to keep the CouchDatabase as a global or create a different cookies store (I did the later in the end).

Comment: Nice one, you should add this as the answer to your own question, so that other people finding your question will be able to see that it's answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was cookie related.

The cookies store in the client was being lost, because I was hosting it in an asp.net application. LoveSeat creates a new cookie store for every instance of CouchDatabase so either I needed to keep the CouchDatabase as a global or create a different cookies store (I did the later in the end).